# How is best to query within a document across fields

Tags: mongodb

I have a bunch of documents like...

```
{
    _id : "abc",
    createdOn : ISODate( '2013-04-27T00:00:00.000Z' ),
    updatedOn : ISODate( '2013-04-27T00:00:00.000Z' )
},
{
    _id : "def",
    createdOn : ISODate( '2013-04-27T00:00:00.000Z' ),
    updatedOn : ISODate( '2013-04-27T00:11:11.111Z' )
}
```

When a document is inserted into the list the createdOn and updatedOn values are equal.  When a document exists, only the updatedOn field gets updated.

I am trying to write the query locating all the documents updatedOn within a specific date range but only want the ones that createdOn != updatedOn.  The query I've got so far works, but I hate it.  I am struggling to figure out how to query across fields without resorting to straight up JavaScript.  Here's what I've got:

```
startTime = ISODate( '2013-04-27T00:00:00.000Z' );
endTime = ISODate( '2013-04-27T01:00:00.000Z' );
db.profiles.find(
  { "updatedOn" : { $gte : startTime, $lt : endTime },
    $where : "obj.createdOn == null || obj.createdOn.getTime() != obj.updatedOn.getTime()"
  },
  {_id: 1, createdOn: 1, updatedOn: 1}
);
```

Is there a better way?  Like something that avoids the $where javascript thing and just lets me compare the document's createdOn to updatedOn fields directly.

Comment: you cannot do this without either javascript or aggregation framework. a work-around would be to add another field to the schema that starts out, say false and gets set to true whenever you update "updated" field.  It would happen atomically and then you can query on that field plus range of updated.  I can write an example up as an answer if it's not clear.

Comment: So that is the best Mongo can do.  Thanks for confirming my suspicion.  I think I'll be coding up some denormalization here.  There's a price to be paid for schemaless, I suppose.

Comment: I think that's more the price you pay for flexible schema :) or the benefit thereof.  You get to design and evolve the schema exactly as you need it to be...